# Inverse function general formula

Tags: functions, inverse-function

I have tried to derive a general formula for an inverse function, but the formula does not produce correct results. Here is my thought process, so I hope you can help me and spot any mistakes. Thank you!

$f(x)=y$

$f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$

$f^{-1}(x) = ?$

---

Let $\frac{f^{-1}(x)}{f(x)} = k,\,k\in \mathbb{R}\;$ *(in the general case, assuming $f(x) \neq 0$)*

Therefore $f^{-1}(x) = k * f(x)$

Then, let's plug in $f(x)$ into $f^{-1}(x)$:

$f^{-1}(f(x)) = k * f(f(x))$

$f^{-1}(f(x)) = x\;$ *(by definition).* So,

$f^{-1}(f(x)) = k * f(f(x)) = x$

Therefore: $\;k = \frac{x}{f(f(x))}$

Thus, the general formula of the inverse function should be:

$f^{-1}(x) = \frac{x}{f(f(x))} * f(x)$

*All is well and beautiful! Except that it doesn't work, at all.* Please help me find and correct this broken piece of math! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that $\frac{f^{-1}(x)}{f(x)}$ is not a constant. That is the mistake.

Comment: Your $k$ defined there depends on the points $x$: if you plug $f(x)$ instead of $x$, this gives another $k$, $k'$, depending on the point $f(x)$.

Comment: When you plug $f(x)$ in place of $x$ you are changing $x$, so to speak, so the value of $k$ will change. It might be clearer to write $k(x)$ instead.